# Why does mineCount return zero?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rows, minesweeper

I wrote some code to count and reveal all adjacent tiles in minesweeper. However, when a tile is revealed and does not contain a mine, it displays zero. The adjacent mines do not get revealed. I'm certain that the issue is in my code. I'm trying to understand where the mistake.
So far I have looked at these suggestions:

[JavaScript Minesweeper - Opening whole mine-free area at once not working properly (flood-fill)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099102/javascript-minesweeper-opening-whole-mine-free-area-at-once-not-working-proper)

https://github.com/franktopel/vue-defuse/blob/master/src/components/VueDefuse.vue#L426

[Minesweeper : Problem to recover the mines adjacent to a tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806921/minesweeper-problem-to-recover-the-mines-adjacent-to-a-tile)

**The code in question:**

```
function buildGrid() {

    // Fetch grid and clear out old elements.
    var grid = document.getElementById("minefield");
    grid.innerHTML = "";

    

    // Build DOM Grid
   
    var tile;
    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            tile = createTile(x,y);
            grid.appendChild(tile);
            //var mine = document.createAttribute("data-mine");
            //mine.value = "false";
            //tile.setAttributeNode(mine);
        }
    }

    var style = window.getComputedStyle(tile);


    var width = parseInt(style.width.slice(0, -2));
    var height = parseInt(style.height.slice(0, -2));
    
    grid.style.width = (columns * width) + "px";
    grid.style.height = (rows * height) + "px";
   
    
}



function createTile(x,y) {
    var tile = document.createElement("div");

    tile.classList.add("tile");
    tile.classList.add("hidden");
    
    tile.addEventListener("auxclick", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }); // Middle Click
    tile.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }); // Right Click
    tile.addEventListener("mouseup", handleTileClick ); // All Clicks

    return tile;

}

function startGame() {
    buildGrid();
    addMines();
    startTimer();
    

    
}

// Left Click
    if (event.which === 1) 
    {
        


        if(tile.classList.contains("mine"))
        {
            tile.classList.toggle("mine_hit");
            smiley.classList.toggle("face_lose");
            window.alert("Game Over. You lose!");
            revealMines();
            stopTimer();
             
        }

        else
        {
            tile.classList.contains("hidden");
            tile.classList.remove("hidden");

             // Count and display the number of adjacent mines
            var mineCount = 0;
            var row = tile.parentElement.rowIndex;  // row gets the rowIndex(tr) 
            var col = tile.cellIndex; //so the columns get the cellIndex

            //alert (tileRow + "" + tileCol);
            for (var i = Math.max(row-1,0); i <= Math.min(row+1); i++)
            {
                for (var j = Math.max(col-1,0); j <=Math.min(col+1); j++)
                {
                    if(grid[i][j].classList.contains("mine"))
                    {
                        mineCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            tile.innerHTML=mineCount;
            if (mineCount===0)
            {
                //Reveal all adjacent tiles as they do not have a mine
                for (var i = Math.max(row -1, 0); i <= Math.min(row +1, 9); i++)
                {
                    for (var j=Math.max(col -1, 0); j <=Math.min(col+1,9); j++)
                    {
                        //recursive call
                        if (grid[i][j].classList.contains("hidden")) handleTileClick(grid[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
                        //checkCompletionLevel();
             
           
        }
        
        
    }
```

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    
        <title>Minesweeper</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/minesweeper.js" ></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Minesweeper </h1>

        <div>
            <select id="difficulty" onchange="setDifficulty();">
               <option value="0">Easy</option>
               <option value="1">Medium</option>
               <option value="2">Hard</option>
            </select>
            
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span>Time:</span>
            <span id="timer" > </span>
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="smiley" class="smiley" onmousedown="smileyDown();" onmouseup="smileyUp();" onclick="startGame();" ></div>
        
        <div id="minefield" >
        </div>
        <!--table id=grid>
        </table-->
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get some feedback on where I went wrong in my code and how to possibly fix it.

Comment: Where is `handleTileClick` defined? Does it contain the javascript code above? If so, does it fail the `event.which === 1` check at the start?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the code you requested above the previous code. To my knowledge it doesn't fail.

Comment: I still don't see the definition of the function `handleTileClick`. It's called in the nested loop at the end, and also as a handler for mouseup events, but I can't see what it does. I'm guessing maybe the `// Left Click` part is actually inside the function definition, or maybe in a function called from it. There may be something wrong with the way it's called or the way arguments are passed on.